# Cisco AnyConnect fails to install on MacOS 10.13.6 latest update due to inability to create /opt/ directory at the root

Tags: macos, high-sierra, vpn

I have been using Cisco AnyConnect through my institution to connect to my work VPN.

However, I have been experiencing issues lately. I cannot even launch or reinstall Cisco AnyConnect on MacOS 10.3.6 (latest update)

I have tried to debug it on my own. I've made some progress to pinpoint the issue. I'll try to summarize it below:

- Cisco AnyConnect tries to install files at the `root` under `/opt/cisco` (while on Mac OS the proper folder seems to be `/usr/local/opt/...`). This is the case across all AnyConnect versions I tried (4.5; 4.6 and 4.8). This does not seem allowed anymore on the latest macOS 10.13.6, thus the failed installation (see points below).
- Looking back at my TimeMachine, I had that `/opt/` folder at the `root` until December 12th  (date of the latest macOS High Sierra update). It actually only contained the Cisco files (proof that there is something uncommon ongoing).
- Since that macOS update in December, the `/opt` folder at the root does not exist anymore (only `/usr/local/opt`). It is not allowed to create that `/opt` directory either. I tried but with no luck, even with admin rights, root user profile and disabling 'System Integrity Protection'. This happens both using the GUI and using the terminal  (`sudo mkdir /opt`). The error messages are not helpful (error 43 in the GUI, and "no such file or directory" message in the terminal). I can create a new folder at the root, as long as it is not named "opt" (if I try to name it `opt` I get the error messages).
- The last thing, I also tried to create `/opt` as a `symlink` to `/usr/local/opt`. No chance there either.

If you have any idea on how to proceed next, that would be great! Thanks a lot for your help (I tried contacting support at Cisco but it seems you need to be the direct, physical client to do so...).